# How to hide an element based instead of removing from DOM

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

I want to be able to show/hide a child LWC in a parent based on a variable (let's say `showOrHideMe`).
But this `showOrHideMe` boolean is coming from child component itself.
Trying the below approach would completely remove the element from dom. But I just want to hide the element allowing it to still present in DOM.

```
<div if:true={showOrHideMe}>
    <c-child-component
       ...
       ...
     >
</div>
```

also tried another approach, I'm setting the showOrHideStyle to `"{display:none}"` if I want to hide.
However this didn't work. I could not know why it doesn't picking the style dyanmically

```
<div style={showOrHideStyle}>
    <c-child-component
       ...
       ...
     >
</div>
```

I know the LWC is quite limited.
But please let me know if there is a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last attempt would work, but you don't use curly brackets in a style attribute:

```
this.showOrHideStyle = 'display:none';
```

Or, you can use the built-in CSS:

```
<div class={showOrHideStyle}>
```

...

```
this.showOrHideStyle = 'slds-hide';
```

Comment: this worked. thanks @sfdcfox !